# Store selenium tests on a server but run them on local browsers, through a framework like fitnesse

Tags: selenium

I've been working on a webdriver framework for a while now, I guess it is
keyword driven now. We would like for there to be a central place for users to
store tests, preferably on a wiki, but then when they are run they would open up
the browser on users local machine.

I originally started working using Fitnesse, which works great for storing the
tests however when we hosted it on a server when a user tries to run a test it
opens the browser on the server which the user can't view. Does anyone know a
way that I could force Fitnesse to open the users local browser or display the
browser to the user? Or do you know another framework/way to store tests in a
central place but run them in local.

I've been looking at sending through the local users ip through a fixture to start up the initial framework, I was hoping that fitnesse would already know the ip.

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either find a framework that does what you want, or the bare minimum would be to create a thin wrapper that copies the test dll's and executeable to a machine and executes psexec to execute the tests on the remote machine.  You could probably write the entire thing in maybe 20 lines of code.